# ADFS 2.0 Error ID4175: The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry

Tags: wif, adfs2.0

The error:

> ID4175: The issuer of the security
>   token was not recognized by the
>   IssuerNameRegistry. To accept security
>   tokens from this issuer, configure the
>   IssuerNameRegistry to return a valid
>   name for this issuer.

The situation: I have 3 or 4 asp.net apps running on a single IIS server (my QA environment), that this morning began returning this error. I start out on an anonymous site, click a link to a secure section, get redirected to my federation services proxy, authenticate, and am redirected back to my secure page, but this error appears.

[This link](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com/2011/02/fixing-id4175-error-message.html) and a bunch of others indicate that the thumbprint in my web.config is wrong, but I can prove (via history in TFS) that the thumbprint in my web.config file has not changed.

I've tried re-running the fedutil, but still get the same message (though that comes up with a different thumbprint). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but it looks like I got bit by [AutoCertificateRollover](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/ad-fs-2-0-how-to-replace-the-ssl-service-communications-token-signing-and-token-decrypting-certificates.aspx) because it worked, and we then re-deployed, replacing the web.config and breaking the authentication.

This was actually a good thing, because our production cert expires in about 6 weeks, and production doesn't have auto rollover enabled - I would have had some serious issues in production and that's never good.